# I'm getting the skin/cloth overlap. What i'm doing wrong?

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm making a GTA style game (I KNOW IS IMPOSSIBLE TO MAKE A GTA BY MYSELF, BUT HEY, I'M YOUNG, HAVE NO FRIENDS, NO GIRLFRINED, WHY NOT SPEND MY FREE TIME DOING WHAT I LIKE THE MOST? :D) and i have a character that constantly change clothes via Menu, what i want is to attach a police uniform (SWAT like) to my character, all animations are done perfectly, until is time to make the Aiming animation, when i do AIMING animationS the skin overlaps the SWAT uniform as you can see on the screenshot
[image: this is the normal aim, frankly, you don't want to see the Top aim animation LOL]

This is the normal aim, frankly, you don't want to see the Top aim animation LOL

I tried everything, weight transfer, data transfer modifier, automatic weight (instead, this is the best i can get, automatic weighting) and i don't want to use alfa mask, becasue the character will be changing clothes during the game and believe me, THERE IS NO TUTORIAL ON HOW TO CHANGE ALPHAS FOR DIFFERENT CLOTHES FOR UNREAL ENGINE 4, ALL INTERNET, NO LUCK, so, alpha is not an option, i ask on all Unreal forums, no answer, search on youtube, no tutorial. How does game modelers animate a clothed character (with changeable clothes)??

I don't know where else to ask, hope you guys can give me a hand, i'll name you on the game credits as helpers!!! I just attached the .BLEND so you guys can check what's wrong with my model.

Here's the blend file
https://mega.nz/#!WFNG0ICY!caklH2v5fP4gSYQNiz-MWpTLibcXXanng2nUMGP90Qs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is more of a suggestion but, does your character need his skin? overlayed clothing is always problematic, and while you can fix it with proper weighting, I feel it would be simpler to just do away with the double layered approach.

If you need different clothes you could have different game models for a few cases, long sleeves, short sleeves, and change the model based on the type of clothing, model data footprint is really low, tough you will have a few contact points where you "weld" the clothing, those can be properly weighted without much effort.

On the topic of alpha masking, not sure if I undertsnad correctly, but changing the alpha of a material at runtime shouldn't be too difficult, provided you are using blueprints/c++.

Comment: Actually he needs, but, thanks for your suggestions, you know how to do that on Unreal? If you know and can teach me, yours will be one of the best answers i ever got. YOU ROCK MAN!!!

Comment: If I'm understanding right and you want to change the alpha values at runtime have a look at this question: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/44139/texture-change-with-blueprint.html

I can vouch that it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely getting this problem because the body and the clothes have different topology and weight values for deformation. Open the clothes in weight paint mode, then add weight on parts where the body is sticking out.